# asp.net mvc 3 change "URL" from "/" to "?id="

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3.  The page contents come from SQL database.  I notice a problem when I try to pass variables using Javascript.  It does not work when the url showing directory/pagename, however it works if the url is directory?=pagename!! Any idea why and how can I change the url to be ?=id.
Here is the action link:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Go", "CourseContent", new { id = Model.ID })%>
```

Routing in Global

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

and here is the controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult CourseContent(long id)
{
   Course requestedCourse = _courseSvc.GetCourse(id);
   if (requestedCourse == null)
       return new HttpNotFoundResult();

    string loggedInUserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    string loggedInRoleName = _membershipSvc.GetRoleForUser(loggedInUserName);

    if (_courseSvc.DetermineIfTheUserCanAttendCourse(id, Request.IsAuthenticated, loggedInUserName, loggedInRoleName))
       return View(requestedCourse);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What doesn't work? How are you calling this url with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with /controller/action/id, but you can always do something like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}?id={id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```